# OneDrive Picker - Extensive permissions

Tags: office365, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using OneDrive File Picker 7.0 SDK. I created an app with the following Microsoft Graph Permissions:

- User.Read
- Fiels.Read.Selected

However, when an authorization dialog appears it shows much more extensive permissions list:

- Sign you in and read your profile
- Have full access to your files
- Sign in as you
- View your basic profile

`Have full access to your files` and `Sign in as you` are particularly scary. How to get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a known issue in their Github issues page https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/461